# Restore minimized application

Tags: delphi-2010

I need to restore and bring to front my application if I try to execute it again. I use the next code to prevent two times execution and to restore it. I've tried everything I've found on stackoverflow about this question but without success. I open my application and I minimize it. Then I try to execute again the application, and it blinks on taskbar but it isn't neither brought to front nor restored.

```
program MyApplication;

uses
  Forms,
  Windows,
  Unit_Form1 in 'Unit_Form1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

var
  RvHandle : Hwnd;

begin

  RvHandle := FindWindow(PWideChar('MyApplication'), NIL);
  if RvHandle > 0 then
  begin
      PostMessage(RvHandle, CM_RESTORE, 0, 0);
      Exit;
  end;

  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.Title := 'My Application';
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

And the form 1:

```
unit Unit_Form1;

interface 

uses ....

const
  CM_RESTORE = WM_USER + $1000;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ....

 private
    procedure ShowTheApplication; 
 protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure RestoreRequest(var message: TMessage); message CM_RESTORE;

 public

 end;

 ...
implementation

...
procedure TForm1.ShowTheApplication;
 var k: integer;
begin
   // iterate backward to ensure that the correct Z-order is preserved
   for k := Screen.FormCount - 1 downto 0 do begin
      Screen.Forms[k].Show;
   end;
end;

 procedure TForm1.RestoreRequest(var message: TMessage);
 begin
    if IsIconic(Application.Handle) = TRUE then ShowTheApplication;
    Application.MainForm.Visible := True;
    ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_RESTORE) ;
    Application.MainForm.WindowState := wsNormal;    // Override minimized state
    Application.BringToFront;
    Application.Restore;
    SetActiveWindow(Application.Handle) ;
    SetForegroundWindow(Application.Handle) ;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
 begin
    inherited CreateParams(Params);
    Params.WinClassName := 'MyApplication';
 end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TJvAppInstances` component from JVCL https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvAppInstances

Or look at the source and get inspired.